# How to run multiple async functions in parallel; where the number of functions to run is inputted by the user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright

Hopefully this isn't too confusing to ask. I am trying to run multiple async functions in parallel. To do this I am using promise.all() which works when I specify the number of async functions such as:

```
await promise.all(func(0), func(1));
```

In the case above I am only running the same function twice and passing a different parameter into each function based off of that function count.

The problem is I would like the user to define the amount of functions they want to run and then the code can call that amount of functions and pass the correct parameter in. So if the user would like the code to run 4 functions, then my promise.all() should look like this:

```
await promise.all(func(0), func(1), func(2), func(3));
```

How should I go about doing this? I would like the code to be able to change the number of functions being passed through in the promise.all().

Comment: What you think you need to do can be done with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) however Promise.all() takes an array of Promises as the only argument.

Comment: In case you didn't realize, your code `await promise.all(func(0), func(1));` does not work.  You have to pass an array of promises as in `await promise.all([func(0), func(1)]);`

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all` takes an array, so you can have an array of functions (of any length) and then do:

```
await Promise.all(allFuncs);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

To be more specific, you can generate that exact set of function calls with:

```
allFuncs = [...Array(count)].map((_, i) => func(i))
```

where `count` is the number of functions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is 'Array' the array of functions? If so I will create the array of functions and then proceed with creating 'allFuncs'. I didn't think of creating an array of functions and you introduced new syntax to me as I am a beginner in js(I have an embedded C background). I will test it out and let you know how it goes!